# Django+Selenium tests give different results with and without coverage

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, selenium

If I run my tests using [coverage](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/), a selenium test fails.  If I run them with `python manage.py test ...`, this test passes.

I have a test suite including some plain python/django tests as well as some tests using Selenium.  CustomWebDriver() is a subclass of selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.

```
class WebDriverITTTests(LiveServerTestCase, Someothermixins):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.webdriver = webdriver.CustomWebDriver()
        super(WebDriverITTTests, cls).setUpClass()

    def test_instructions_logic(self):
        ...
        login, check that some things happened on the server side
        open a page, check for "#some_element" loaded via ajax
        ...
```

The `test_instructions_logic` test fails when I run it under coverage because it fails to find `"#some_element"`.

Coverage command: `coverage run --source mymodule.subapp manage.py test mymodule.subapp --settings myproj.settings`

Manage.py command: `python manage.py test mymodule.subapp --settings myproj.settings`

Why are the tests results different in these two cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was using [this](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/introduction-django-selenium-testing/) as a reference, and the problem was...

1. When using Selenium find_element_by_blah(), if the element is loaded via Ajax, you need to wait until it's loaded before looking for it.  Hence the `wait_for_css()` method in the link. (I was indeed using that method).
2. The difference between the `manage.py` test runner and `coverage test` running is probably due to time - if I added a time.sleep(2) before checking for the element, the test would pass in both cases.
3. But why doesn't the `wait_for_css` method prevent this problem???
4. Because I naively created the `NoSuchElementException`, like

   ```
   class NoSuchElementException(Exception)
       pass
   ```

   instead of importing it: `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException` (and thus `find_css` method from the link was raising a different exception than what Selenium was expecting, and failing and exiting instead of waiting).

Oy.